# Catching any webservice exception?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap

I have a soap `@webservice`, and a client sending requests as below:

```
try {
  // any webservice confniguration here
  webservice.call();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("ERROR");
}
```

Now if the connections time out, I'm getting a `java.net.socketTimtoutException` with `stacktrace`, plus my error sysouts above. How can I prevent the stacktrace from being printed to console? I don't understand why I ever get it as I'm catching any occuring exception, aren't I?

Comment: Somewhere, a try/catch catches the exception, prints it, and then rethrows it.  You will have to investigate deeper.

Comment: Try writing other instructions after your `try/catch` block to see if they are reached like `System.out`

Comment: Yes they are. The code continues, somehow the ex is thrown in between, but without me specifiying this...

Comment: It might be the framework printing the exception before throwing it... which class prints the exception? Maybe you can post the whole stacktrace...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then it's clearly obvious that somewhere in between, a `try/catch` block catches the exception, prints the stack trace, and then rethrows it. As @WernerVesterås said.
I can advise you to debug the code.